# What is the difference between ‘red’ and ‘redness’?

Tags: difference

Do ‘red’ and ‘redness’ mean the same thing? That is, color red is quality redness?

Red: red color

Redness: the quality or state of being red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Red" is most often used as an attribute:

> A red apple.  Her face was red.  A big red light.

You could not replace the adjective "red" with "redness" in these examples.

As a noun it is the name of a colour.

> Crimson is a dark red.

And it is used to mean "a red thing" in a variety of contexts:

> Would you like the red [wine]?  There are reds [communists] everywhere.  He potted a red [ball in snooker]

"redness" isn't the name of a colour. You can use it to describe how red something is:

> The redness of the room is shocking!

or often to talk about medical inflammation

> Redness of the skin can indicate an infection.

Comment: Then, ‘dark red’ is correct and ‘dark redness’ is wrong because ‘redness’ is something is red, not red itself.

Comment: Dark red is correct. Dark redness would be rare (if the redness in the inflammation was also dark for example)